# BigQuery: How to create integer partitioned table via DML?

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, integer-partition

I try to understand how the integer partitioned tables work. So far however, I could not create one.

What is wrong with this query:

```
 #standardSQL
 CREATE or Replace TABLE temp.test_int_partition

 PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(id, GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100))
 OPTIONS(
   description="test int partition"
 ) 
as 

WITH data as (
SELECT 12 as id, 'Alex' as name
UNION ALL 
SELECT 23 as id, 'Chimp' as name
)

SELECT *
from data
```

I'm getting this error:

`Error: PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>), a DATE column, or RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>, <int64_value>))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that despite `GENERATE_ARRAY` being documented as `GENERATE_ARRAY(start_expression, end_expression [, step_expression])`, meaning **`step_expression`** being optional, for the `RANGE_BUCKET` it's **mandatory**.

So the following will work:

```
 #standardSQL
 CREATE or Replace TABLE temp.test_int_partition

 PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(id, GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100,1))
 OPTIONS(
   description="test int partition"
 ) 
as 

WITH data as (
SELECT 12 as id, 'Alex' as name
UNION ALL 
SELECT 23 as id, 'Chimp' as name
)

SELECT *
from data
```

Comment: yes. After I  tried entering the optional parameter it worked

Comment: I can't for the next two days